# densities being absolutely continuous wrt Lebesgue measure

Tags: probability, measure-theory, statistics

I'm reading an article with an assumption similar to: "The density $f(.)$  exists and is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure". I don't understand this assumption because $f$ is not a measure. Can someone enlighten me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Read: $f$ is the [Radon-Nikodym derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem) (density) of a measure $\mu$ with respect to Lebesgue measure (and $\mu$ is absolutley continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure.)

Answer (score 1):

It's just lazy writing. It means that the measure is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure, Hence the density $f(\cdot)$ exists.

Comment: Thanks, however, then the statements $f$ exists and is absolutely continuous wrt the Lebesgue measure would be redundant.

Comment: Yes, it's technically an error, but these things usually slip through in very applied papers where not everybody remembers their measure theory.